# pandas slightly changes assigned value

Tags: python, pandas

I'm assigning a value to a specific pandas location. However, the value seems to slightly change for some reason. Does anyone know why this happens? I posted a snippet of my code below. I added the prints statements to see in more detail what happens, but it makes no sense to me.

```
if entry != None:

orders.iloc[index, orders.columns.get_loc('start_time_corrected')] = entry['t'].astype(np.int64)

print(entry['t'].astype(np.int64))                                
print(int(orders.iloc[index]['start_time_corrected']))

print(np.datetime64(int(orders.iloc[index]['start_time_corrected']),'ns'))
print(entry['t'])
```

which gives the following output:

```
1615606416410318537
1615606416410318592

2021-03-13T03:33:36.410318592
2021-03-13T03:33:36.410318537
```

as you can see the value in the output slightly changes, even though it should be the same value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a lost of casting from `int` to `numpy.int64` going on here and that is why you have a difference in values.

Because you are casting `orders.iloc[index]['start_time_corrected']` to `int` before  you print it, you are going to lose information as python allocates 32-bits for for a normal integer type while numpy's `np.int64` datatype is allocated 64 bits.

Comment: Thanks for the reaction! However, it also occurs when I cast np.````np.int64```` on the value. It seems as if pandas stores the value as an ````np.float64```` and sometime goes wrong when cast this to an ````int````? Would this be possible?